# TypeError: 'ResultProxy' object does not support indexing when trying to store user ID in sessions

Tags: python-3.x, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

In my `Signedup` route I am trying to store user id in session and log users in automatically but when I try to do so I get this error:

`TypeError: object of type 'ResultProxy' does not support indexing`

And, In my `signin` route I am trying to remember which user has logged in but here I get error:

`TypeError: object of type 'ResultProxy' has no len()`

`signedup` route in `application.py`

```
@app.route("/signedup",methods=["GET","POST"])
def signedup():
    if request.method=="POST":
        password = request.form.get("password")
        hash = pwd_context.encrypt(password)


        name = request.form.get("name")



        if not name:
            return "must provide username"
        elif not password:
            return "must provide password"



        registration = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES (:username,:password)",
                    {"username":name,"password":hash})

        if not registration:
            return "pick a different username"


        # Store their ID in session and log them in automatically

     user_id = db.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users where username = :username",{"username":name})        
            # It means something like - "give me the first row in result

            # and retrieve the value of the key "id"
#ERROR
            session["user_id"] = user_id[0]["id"]      
            db.commit()

            return render_template("success.html",name = name)
        else:
            return render_template("signup.html")
```

`signin` route in `application.py`

```
@app.route("/signin",methods=["GET","POST"])
def signin():
    # LOG A USER IN
    #forget any user_id
    session.clear()

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("login.html")

    else:
        user_name = request.form.get("username")

        # ensure username is provided
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return "must provide username"

        # ensure password is provided
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return "must provide password"


        # query the database for the username
        rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM users where username = :username",{"username":user_name})

        # ensure username exists 
        if len(rows) != 1 or not pwd_context.verify(request.form.get("password"),rows[0]["hash"]):
            return "Invalid username"

        # remember which user has logged in 
        session["user_id"] = rows[0]["id"]
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error and solved by adding .fetchone() at the end of db.execute command:

```
user_id = db.execute("SELECT user_id FROM users where username = :username",{"username":name}).fetchone()
```

You have to use .fetchone (to return a single result) or .fetchall (to return all results) to be able to use indexes on resultProxy objects returned by SQLAlchemy commands.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply iterate over resultProxy object.

```
for iter in user_id:
   session["user_id"] = iter[0]
```

Comment: rly this is necessary... wtf